# this.state is undefined inside function - React JS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why do i get state is undefined here? I tried various solutions but none worked for me. Can someone point out what am doing wrong here

Edit:

Complete Code of the component

```
  class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        menuSelected: menuOptions.menuItems[0].title,
      }
      this.createMenuListItem = this.createMenuListItem.bind(this)
    }
    render () {
      console.log(this.state.menuSelected)
      function getChildItems (child) {
        let childItems = child.children.map(function (menuItem, index) {
          return createMenuListItem(menuItem)
        })
        return (
          <li key={child.title} className='dropdown'>
            <i className={child.iconName} />
            <span className='dropdown-toggle'>{child.title}</span>
            <ul className=''>
              {childItems}
            </ul>
          </li>
        )
      }
      function createMenuListItem (menuItem) {
        if (menuItem.hasChild === 'N') {
          console.log(this.state.menuSelected)
          return (
            <li key={menuItem.title}>
              <a href='#'>
                <i className={menuItem.iconName} />
                <span>{menuItem.title}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          )
        } else {
          return getChildItems(menuItem)
        }
      }

      let menuItemsLoaded = menuOptions.menuItems.map((menuItem, index) => {
        return createMenuListItem(menuItem)
      })
      return (
        <nav id='sidebar'>
          <ul className='list-unstyled'>
            {menuItemsLoaded}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      )
    }
  }

  export default Sidebar
```

Also can somebody possibly suggest a better option when the sidebar content is loaded dynamically from the server

Comment: because you need to bind the function `createMenuListItem` with `this`.

Comment: i tried adding this in constuctor


this.createMenuListItem = this.createMenuListItem.bind()


 but i get following error"Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: this is wrong ` this.createMenuListItem.bind()` should be `this.createMenuListItem = this.createMenuListItem.bind(this)`

Comment: still i get the same error "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By using `function` you sort of lose the context and `this` is not the one you were expecting.

In this case, either use arrow function as:

```
render() {
  createMenuItems = (items) => {
    console.log(this.state.menuSelected)
    ...
  }
}
```

Or, *and here comes my suggestion*, move `createMenuItems` outside of `render` method:

```
createMenuItems = (items) => {
  console.log(this.state.menuSelected)
}

render() {
  return (
    <nav id='sidebar'>
      <ul className='list-unstyled'>
        {menumenuOptions.menuItems.map((menuItem, index) =>
          this.createMenuListItem(menuItem)
        )}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Binding it in the constructor is also a possibility:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      menuSelected: '',
    }

    this.createMenuListItem = this.createMenuListItem.bind(this)
  }

  createMenuListItem() {
    console.log(this.state.menuSelected)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav id='sidebar'>
        <ul className='list-unstyled'>
          {menumenuOptions.menuItems.map((menuItem, index) =>
            this.createMenuListItem(menuItem)
          )}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: createMenuListItem calls another function.

when i move both the functions outside render method. I get function is not defined error

Comment: @Mr.Noob so maybe share a bit more of your code :)

Comment: added complete code

Comment: Worked thanks....had to convert to even the map method inside function into arrow